# Global existence of a dynamical problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Prove that all the solutions to the system
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot x= e^{-y^2}\sin(x^n+y^n),
\\
\dot y= x^n\sin(x^n+y^n),
\end{cases}
$$
where $n$ is a fixed natural number, are defined on $[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I was able to prove that if $n$ is even then the solution must be global, because you have that the solution can't intersect the closed curves $x^n+y^n=2k\pi$ (the points on the curves are solutions too). But it doesn't work when $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=(x,y):[0,T)\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be a solution with $X(0)=(x_0,y_0)$. We need to show that $T=\infty$. Note that

$$\tag{1}
 \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
 x(t)= x_0+\int_0^t e^{-y(s)^2}\sin{(x(s)^n+y(s)^n)}&\mbox{ } \\
  y(t)= y_0+\int_0^t x(s)^n\sin{(x(s)^n+y(s)^n)} &\mbox{}
       \end{array} \right.
$$

If $T<\infty$, we conclude from $(1)$ that $|x(t)|<\infty$ for $t\in [0,T)$, which implies also that $|y(t)|<\infty$ for $t\in [0,T)$. Thus, there is a ball $B$ such that the solution $X$ does not leave $B$.

Once the function $(e^{-y^2}\sin{(x^n+y^n)},x^n\sin{(x^n+y^n)} )$ is bounded in $B$, we must conclude that $X(t)\to a\in\mathbb{R}^2$ if $t\to T$, which is an absurd.